# make elements shine at variable times

Tags: html, css, animation

I've created a **CSS** animation which animates a 'shine' effect on all the elements with the specified class.

The shine itself works perfect, however, due to them all shining at the same time, it looks fairly *unnatural*.

I've been brainstorming different ways to variate the shine times for each element - but I can't seem to wrap my head around it, and none of the things I've tried are either efficient, or just don't work altogether.

```css
    .loading-element{
        position: relative;
        background: #e0e0e0;
    }
    .loading-element::after{ /* this is the animated pseudo-element */
     content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,
           rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 50%,
           rgba(247,247,247,0) 99%,
           rgba(247,247,247,0) 100%);
        transform: translateX(100%);
        animation: shine 1s infinite 3s;
    }
    .index-load_track-item{
        width: 426px;
        height: 117px;
        margin: 30px 0;
    }
    .index-load-track_outer-artwork, .index-load-track_outer-waveform{
     float: left;
    }
    .index-load-track_outer-artwork{
        width: 117px;
        height: 117px;
        margin-right: 9px;
    }
    .index-load-track_outer-artwork .loading-element{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    }
    .index-load-track_outer-waveform{
        width: 300px;
        height: 60px;
    }
    .index-load-track_outer-waveform .loading-element{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    /* animation */
    @keyframes shine{
     0%{ transform:translateX(-100%); }
     100%{ transform:translateX(100%); }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="index-load_track-item">
      <div class="index-load-track_outer-artwork">
      <div class="loading-element"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="index-load-track_outer-waveform">
      <div class="loading-element"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="index-load_track-item">
      <div class="index-load-track_outer-artwork">
      <div class="loading-element"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="index-load-track_outer-waveform">
      <div class="loading-element"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet for you - I am pretty sure this will be off topic as a _primarily opinion-based_ type question

Comment: @mplungjan (not being rude) but just curious how this is _"primarily opinion-based"_?

Comment: _it looks fairly unnatural. I've been brainstorming different ways to variate the shine times for each element_ Seems like you do not like it, and ask for suggestions to change it in some way or another in an unspecified way. I have NOT voted to close. Just wanted to mention it

Comment: @mplungjan ah, that's fair enough! thanks for explaining :)

Comment: It’d probably make the most sense, if you simply applied different animation-delays. Negative values allow to create a “delayed start” of the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use some jQuery, I'll suggest you to do something like this:
(I added some CSS code with comments to avoid unwanted behaviour)

```js
// On load, add random delays and durations to each of the ".loading-element"s
$('.loading-element').each(function(e) {
  $(this).css({
    "animation-delay": (-10 * Math.random()) + "s",
    "animation-duration": (1 + 2 * Math.random()) + "s"
  });
});
```

```css
.loading-element {
  position: relative;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  /* Added below to avoid the shine being outside
  and the scroll bars to appear as in your snippet */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.loading-element::after {
  /* this is the animated pseudo-element */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  filter: blur(5px); /* Added, just to try with it */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 50%, rgba(247, 247, 247, 0) 99%, rgba(247, 247, 247, 0) 100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* animation: shine 1s infinite 3s; 
  now decomposed as below: */
  animation-name: shine;
  animation-duration: inherit;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: inherit;
}

.index-load_track-item {
  width: 426px;
  height: 117px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.index-load-track_outer-artwork,
.index-load-track_outer-waveform {
  float: left;
}

.index-load-track_outer-artwork {
  width: 117px;
  height: 117px;
  margin-right: 9px;
}

.index-load-track_outer-artwork .loading-element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.index-load-track_outer-waveform {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
}

.index-load-track_outer-waveform .loading-element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* animation */

@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="index-load_track-item">
  <div class="index-load-track_outer-artwork">
    <div class="loading-element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index-load-track_outer-waveform">
    <div class="loading-element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="index-load_track-item">
  <div class="index-load-track_outer-artwork">
    <div class="loading-element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index-load-track_outer-waveform">
    <div class="loading-element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

This can also be done using CSS variables!
If you can use it, it's a better and easier way to do it, in my humble opinion.

```js
// On load, add random delays and durations to each of the ".loading-element"s
$('.loading-element').each(function(e) {
  $(this).css({
    "--shine-delay": (-10 * Math.random()) + "s",
    "--shine-duration": (1 + 2 * Math.random()) + "s"
  });
});
```

```css
.loading-element {
  position: relative;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  /* Added below to avoid the shine being outside
  and the scroll bars to appear as in your snippet */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.loading-element::after {
  /* this is the animated pseudo-element */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  /* top and bottom modified so that blur doesn't add empty bars */
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  filter: blur(8px); /* Added, just to try with it */
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 10%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 50%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 90%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
  );
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: shine var(--shine-duration) infinite var(--shine-delay); /* <3 */
}

.index-load_track-item {
  width: 426px;
  height: 117px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.index-load-track_outer-artwork,
.index-load-track_outer-waveform {
  float: left;
}

.index-load-track_outer-artwork {
  width: 117px;
  height: 117px;
  margin-right: 9px;
}

.index-load-track_outer-artwork .loading-element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.index-load-track_outer-waveform {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
}

.index-load-track_outer-waveform .loading-element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* animation */

@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="index-load_track-item">
  <div class="index-load-track_outer-artwork">
    <div class="loading-element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index-load-track_outer-waveform">
    <div class="loading-element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="index-load_track-item">
  <div class="index-load-track_outer-artwork">
    <div class="loading-element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="index-load-track_outer-waveform">
    <div class="loading-element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.